# I have 13 Ruby processes running on mac and I don't know whats causing them?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

[image]After running top -o cpu

Im seeing 13 instances of Ruby near the top. They are only using a very small amount of CPU but I can't figure whats causing them to run?

iMac 4GB RAM OSx Lion.

Just ran f-secure flashBack checker and my iMac is apparently not infected.
Also according to top _devicemgr is the user for the ruby processes

Comment: Is this a coding question or a systems question?  Do you do ruby development and possibly created these processes yourself, or are you worried because you don't know how they could have been started?

Comment: Im not doing any Ruby development thats the thing. I don't know why there are so many processes running?

Comment: any more details on the processes?  is the name just ruby?  You might try ps auxww |grep ruby to see if there are additional arguments to the commands

Comment: Not to be alarmist, but I think there's a variant of the Flashback malware about that has a Ruby payload. Of course you might just be running some app that uses Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search for the usernames that appear in your screenshot, you will find that they (e.g. `_teamsserver`) belong to certain OS X Lion server processes. For example, these are related to Wiki services.

Therefore, there's nothing to worry about. These are *not* malicious. And unless they're using up more CPU than you want, you can keep everything enabled.